# RotationY Matrix4 not rotating fully

Tags: flutter

I have a text widget I want to rotate for 360 degrees only on Y axis.

Here is the code I currently have, it only rotates up to a certain point.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _rotate;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _rotate = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 3.14 * 2).animate(_controller);
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        child: Text("Flutter"),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.rotationY(_controller.value),
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: where is `_rotate` used? i dont see it anywhere... also use `pi` from `dart:math`, and not magic `3.14`

Comment: @pskink `_rotate` is being connected to `_controller` in `initState()`, right?

Comment: @pskink thank you! changing param to use `_rotate.value` instead of `_controller.value' did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
_rotate = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 3.14 * 2).animate(_controller)
..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
```